# Why WordPress image link in not appearing after activating SSL?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've successfully added SSL on my WordPress website and it's every URL is working well with https URL but there seems all images is missing. In dashboard, all images URL is converted to https URL but in front-end they are not showing any URL it just seems like

Please anyone could help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you paste code from your template, and the code for functions (If the template uses any, other than core functions)? Is there any plugin you're using for images?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the URLs to the images are now http, and may be being blocked by browser security settings. There's a handy plugin I often use to help sort out issues like this called Really Simple SSL:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

This plugin manages the URLs to include the correct protocol, etc. You may need to change any hard-coded URLs in your theme that do not use https however.

Comment: No no. I think not this issue. The URL is changed to https in the dashboard. But in the front-end is not showing any url. look this example http://prntscr.com/cnjkeg

In dashbord the image are seted and there the links is with https.

Comment: While I think it'd still be worth the time to try installing the plugin I mentioned, I also notice that you've got 3 console errors in your developer console. Can you post the output of those here?

Comment: I've installed the plugin but the problem isn't fixed. :( Here is screenshot of console error http://prntscr.com/cnoss5
U can also check my site from here: https://thecreativecomposite.co.uk/